# how to create a map with a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a dataframe, **df.show()** like this:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
|id|                        name|
+-----------+-------------------+
|       1231|                aa |
|       1232|                bb |
|       1233|                cc |
|       1234|                dd |
|       1235|                 dd|
|       1236|                 cc|
+-----------+-------------------+
```

the column "id" is unique, now I would create a map which key is "id",value is "name",how to realize it by scala? assume dataframe name is df.

```
val mapResult = df.map(...)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply convert to `rdd` and use `collectAsMap`

```
df.rdd.map(x => (x.getInt(0), x.getString(1))).collectAsMap()
```

This will give you

```
scala>  df.rdd.map(x => (x.getInt(0), x.getString(1))).collectAsMap()
res0: scala.collection.Map[Int,String] = Map(1231 -> aa, 1234 -> dd, 1236 -> cc, 1233 -> cc, 1232 -> bb, 1235 -> dd)
```

collectAsMap is only recommended when your data fits in a driver.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but the result type is Predef.Map,I want to get a collection.Map map, what should I use? sorry I am a fresh man was learning scala

Comment: the result type os of `scala.collection.Map[Int,String]`  as you can see above